# Modify custom TableViewCell size based on contents

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to resize my custom TableViewCell to wrap its contents, which can be a variably-sized image and/or any number of lines of text, followed by a vote bar.

My OMCFeedTableViewCell looks like this:

[image: Prototype Cell]

I have tried setting up contraints, modifying frames, nothing works correctly.

This is my code so far:

In FeedViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OMCFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OMCFeedTableViewCell
    let p = posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let data = p.content!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let content = try! JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers))
    let image = content["image"].string

    let uploads = uploadAPI()
    uploads.tryGetImage(image) {
        (result: UIImage?) in

        if let i = result {
            cell.postImage.image = i
            cell.postImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
            let containerWidth = cell.postImage.frame.width
            let aspectRatio = i.size.height / i.size.width
            let scaledHeight = aspectRatio * containerWidth
            // do something with the calculated height
        } else {
            // kill the imageview
        }
    }
    if let text = content["text"].string {
        cell.postText.text = text
        // calculate the textview height
    } else {
        // kill the text section
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if heights[indexPath.row] == nil {
        // calculate the correct overall height
    }
    return heights[indexPath.row]!
}
```

In OMCFeedTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class OMCFeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var voteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downVoteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var upVoteButton: UIButton!

}
```

Comment: have you tried `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`?

Comment: That works a treat. I couldn't find that ANYWHERE on google!!! Mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: Nice, cheers. Also read the answer for extra stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and it would automatically adjust your cell size depending on contents.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

also set your `estimatedRowHeigh`

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
```

Also from experience, sometime the bottom constraint on main content view has given me a problem, you can remove it if it bothered you.